# Why are there #text nodes in my xml file?

Tags: android, dom, xml-parsing

I'm making an android application that does DOM parsing on an xml file. I have an xml file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<family>
    <grandparent>
        <parent1>
            <child1>Foo</child1>
            <child2>Bar</child2>
        </parent1>
        <parent2>
            <child1>Raz</child1>
            <child2>Mataz</child2>
        </parent2>
    </grandparent>  
</family>
```

If I run a dom parser on it, like this:

```
try {
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        
    Document doc = builder.parse(input);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();   //added in since the edit
    NodeList nodd = doc.getElementsByTagName("grandparent");
    for (int x = 0; x < nodd.getLength(); x++){
        Node node = nodd.item(x);
        NodeList nodes = node.getChildNodes();
        for(int y = 0; y < nodes.getLength(); y++){
            Node n = nodes.item(y);
            System.out.println(n.getNodeName());
        }
    }
}
```

My application prints out the following

> 07-20 18:24:28.395: INFO/System.out(491): #text
>
> 07-20 18:24:28.395: INFO/System.out(491): parent1
>
> 07-20 18:24:28.395: INFO/System.out(491): #text
>
> 07-20 18:24:28.395: INFO/System.out(491): parent2
>
> 07-20 18:24:28.395: INFO/System.out(491): #text

My question is, what are those #text fields and more importantly, how do I get rid of them?

**Edit:** So now that I know what they are, I tried to normalize it. I have updated the code to reflect the changes, but same result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's whitespace (newlines, spaces, tabs) :)

Comment: How could I check for it? I suppose I can do a `getNextSibling()` but can I count on there always being a `#text` as the first child?

Comment: You can't count on #text being first, because there may be some later.  What do you mean by removing, though?  If you are gathering up all the nodes and outputting them somewhere, just check each node as you generate them, look at its type and if it is #text AND the content is all whitespace, simply just don't output it.

Comment: I suppose removing was a bad term, I'm running on a guarantee that there will be no text where #text is. But you brought up exactly what I was looking for. I can run a check on the getNodeType(). Thanks.

Comment: Glad it works.  I checked on the definition of `normalize` and it will remove completely empty text nodes, but not those consisting entirely of whitespace.  So yes ignoring is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you get :

1) A node list with all the nodes being the grand-parents

```
NodeList nodd = doc.getElementsByTagName("grandparent");
```

2) All the child node of the grand parent x

```
NodeList nodes = node.getChildNodes();
```

which are the sub nodes of

```
< grandparent >
    < parent1 >
       ...
    < /parent1 >

    < parent2 >
       ...
    < /parent2 >
< /grandparent >
```

3) The child y

```
nodes.item(y);
```

There could be text between  and  this is the #text you have, if you had :

```
< grandparent >
    yourTextHere1
    < parent1 >
       ...
    < /parent1 >
    yourTextHere2
    < parent2 >
       ...
    < /parent2 >
    yourTextHere3
< /grandparent >
```

You would get :

yourTextHere1
parent1
yourTextHere2
parent2
yourTextHere3

I hope it helped you ! 
Julien,

Comment: So how would I get rid of text children or test for text children?

Comment: Document doc = builder.parse(input); 
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize(); 
As my colleague said a message up from mine :)

Comment: that's what I'm thinking but can I be sure that they will always be every other?

Comment: To my mind yes, if not it means it's not formated in XML. There may be another solution (that i don't know) but that's the one I used and never had problem till now...

Comment: I found this as well, depending on the parser you are using there may be a function like bool isContentWhiteSpace() or a property you can get ... see this http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/dom_text.asp

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize there was a getNodeType(), which will tell you if it's an element or text child so I'm using that.

Answer (score 0):

Do this when parsing the document,

```
Document doc = builder.parse(input); 
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

This would kind of deflate the xml file and remove all unwanted #text children.

Comment: I tested this, it did not work. I still see the #text children.