# Android XML parser fetch key-value pairs

Tags: android

I'm trying to parse an XML file. The format of the XML file is:

```
<Testcase>
    <Title>Low Load</Title>
    <MO_Call>DIAL</MO_Call>
    <Delay>10</Delay>
    <MO_Call>HANGUP</MO_Call>
    <Delay>10</Delay>
    <MO_SMS>SEND</MO_SMS>
</Testcase>
```

I need to get the key-value pairs under the node "Testcase" and store in a datastructure. Ordering is important, and hence I'm considering a LinkedHashMap.

Please suggest the right way to get the key-value pairs from the XMl file.
In the above XML snippet, the corresponnding key-value pairs are:
Key: MO_Call, Value: DIAL
Key: Delay, Value: 10

I have written the below code for parsing the XML:

```
try {
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(new FileInputStream(CONFIG_PATH));
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName(TAG_TEST_CASE);
    if (nodeList != null && nodeList.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i=0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Element el = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
            // If title doesn't match, check the next title under next 'Testcase' NodeList
            if(el.getFirstChild().getNodeName().equals(TAG_TITLE) &&
                    !el.getFirstChild().getNodeValue().equals(title)) {
                continue;
            }
            // else, title matches. So parse the child nodes.
            // Start from index 1, since index 0 is title always
            NodeList childNodeList = el.getChildNodes();
            for(int j=1; j < childNodeList.getLength(); j++) {
                Node childNode = childNodeList.item(j);
                //Element childElement = (Element) childNodeList.item(j);
                Log.d("Tool", "key=" +childNode.getNodeName()+ ", value=" +childNode.getTextContent());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the output:

```
key=Title, value=Low Load
key=#text, value=
key=MO_Call, value=DIAL
key=#text, value=
key=Delay, value=10
key=#text, value=
key=MO_Call, value=HANGUP
key=#text, value=
key=Delay, value=10
key=#text, value=
key=MO_SMS, value=SEND
key=#text, value=
key=Title, value=Medium Load
key=#text, value=
key=Title, value=High Load
key=#text, value=
```

For some reason, the key "#text" is coming up along with null value. Please help me avoid this.

Comment: That XML is very badly structured. There should be no reliance on ordering of elements in XML. If you are able to change the way the XML file is generated then I'd suggest you do so.

Comment: @Squonk: By ordering, I meant that the items need to be executed in the same order as they appear in under the "Testcase" tag. For example, after parsing the XML, MO call will happen first, followed by a delay of 10 seconds, and then Hangup of the MO call, followed by another delay of 10 seconds, and then SMS is sent.

Comment: @Squonk Android Layouts rely heavily on ordering on an XML, as does JavaFX.

Comment: could you please check if the empty value comes from the whitespace characters before and after the tags (simply remove the line breaks and white space)? It seems to me that the indention is read as a text node.

Comment: @Denis: yes, that seems like a sure cause. Will check this and update soon. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @m0skit0 : "Android Layouts rely heavily on ordering on an XML..." - Not strictly true. That may be the case for `LinearLayout` from a design perspective but when using a `RelativeLayout` it's possible to declare a UI element meant to go below another *before* you've declared the UI element it's supposed to go below. Android layout XML files are pre-processed at compile time for optimisation - ordering is only important based on the `ViewGroup` type. I stand by my comment that the ordering / structure of that XML is poor - the OP may as well use a simple text file and read line by line.

Comment: @Denis: I removed the formatting from the XML and the "#text" keys with null values are still showing up

Answer (score 0):

Please, [reffer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766721/why-are-there-text-nodes-in-my-xml-file) for the `#text`. If you can alter the XML, remove ALL spaces that are unintentional, then re-test your code.

Example XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Testcase><Title>Low Load</Title><MO_Call>DIAL</MO_Call><Delay>10</Delay><MO_Call>HANGUP</MO_Call><Delay>10</Delay><MO_SMS>SEND</MO_SMS></Testcase>
```

Also, please show the encode used on the XML file, there could be typos.

[This is also a good suggestion on how to parse](http://www.sitepoint.com/learning-to-parse-xml-data-in-your-android-app/)